# how to implement rest api to radial bar chart recharts react.js?

Tags: reactjs, api, bar-chart, recharts, radial

How to implement rest api to radial bar chart in react.js using rechart?

I can't call my api to my radial bar chart using rechart.

https://recharts.org/en-US/api/RadialBar

Comment: Hi Narul ! You can check the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to write you question with more details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component where you call your REST API using axios for example

```
 getData = async (): Promise<string> => {
       let dataJSON = await axios.get('http://webcode.me');
            return dataJSON;
        }
    };
```

Then you can display your chart as shown in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-radial-bar-chart-qf8fz